# recursive function generating "Type 'never' cannot be used as an index type."

Tags: typescript

I wanted to write a recursive private function within a class that looped through the nested properties of an object (where the object can have any number of nested properties)

```
private loop(item:any) {

    for(let property in item){

      if (typeof property === "object") {
        this.loop(item[property]);
        continue;
      }

      console.log(property)

    }
  }
```

in itself, this is a useless function - but it generates an error when compiling

> Type 'never' cannot be used as an index type.

To be honest, I have no idea why, or what this error is ... I have looked up the docs, but all the examples seem to talk about is an unsatisfied switch statement.

Using typescript 2.3.4

I would appreciate it if some kind soul was able to enlighten me ;)

Comment: How can `property` be an object? I thought property names had to be strings.

Comment: oh .. dear .. god ... yes. It should have been typeof item[property]

Thanks. now I feel very foolish ;)

Answer (score 0):

yes, I had a typo. I should have said

```
typeof item[property]
```

sorry for the waste of bandwidth ;)